# Migrate From Groupwise to Thunderbird

Tags: migration, contacts, thunderbird, mozilla

I have successfully set up sending and receiving email in the Thunderbird for my Groupwise account. But, I am missing the feature that suggests contacts when I start typing their name in the To field (or cc or bcc).

Is there a way to connect thunderbird to the groupwise contacts? If not is there a way to manually import the contacts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird supports on-the-fly LDAP lookups.  I've used this setup with ActiveDirectory for 3+ years now.  If you can get Groupwise to provide you with LDAP support, you're set.

Comment: Cool! That worked. I found Zindus for also syncing my gmail contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Failing that, you can also use something like GWIMPEXP (http://www.slewis.org/) to export the GroupWise address book into a format that Thunderbird can make sense of.